# How to make a video presentation with a video of the slideshow and a video of me speaking in the corner?

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, mac, presentation

I am a teacher and I am trying to sync my slideshow presentation to a video of me speaking about the slideshow presentation. I'm trying to make it so that the presentation takes up most of the screen, and the recorded video of me speaking takes up a corner just outside of the slideshow area.

I have a Mac, so any suggestions with mac-based programs would be preferable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Preferable depends... But possibilities are for example: MacOS offers the App iMovie which is available with no further cost. For more professional video editing you can use e.g. Adobe Premiere or Final Cut, but then you need to pay and you need much more effort doing research to get familiar with it. To sync two videos and the iMovie App will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you've made the slideshow in Powerpoint (if not, please provide details) - in Powerpoint you can export your slideshow as an MP4. Go to the "File" menu, select "Export", and choose MP4 as the file format. Review your output video file, and go back and adjust your slide timings as required if you need alter the speed of the presentation.

Now you have a video of your presentation, record the video of you to go along with it. I would play the first video where you can see it, while you record the second one, so you can get the timing correct for them to be in sync.

The final step is to overlay the second video in the corner of the first one. Software like Adobe Premiere Pro can do this easily, if you don't have it, you can likely download the trial version and just use that, if this is a one-off for you. Add the 2 videos to the timeline, on the Effects panel use the Motion settings to scale down the size and adjust position of the second video, and make sure it is layered on top of the first one. I suspect there are various free tools around that can overlay the two videos as well, I'm just not familiar with them - hopefully someone else can jump in with some other options here if needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenflow](https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) is really great for this kind of thing. It's not free ($129), and is designed for Mac. It's great for making polished screen recordings.  You can record your webcam, your mic, the computer screen/s, and any computer audio as separate tracks, which you can edit afterwards in the app. You can remove your mouse cursors afterwards, or call attention to it at certain times. I highly recommend it (just don't record to an external drive with limited space in Uncompressed mode - it eats a lot of space while recording).

You can also now [use live video cameras inside Apple Keynote](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/keynote/tan6a7b90433/mac), and [record a presentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/keynote/tan81813d552/mac) within Keynote too.

Answer (score 0):

DaVinci Resolve offers a free version which is fully capable, and available for Mac, Windows, and Linux.